# Navigation controller did not show up on contactsUI forNewcontact

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, contacts-framework

Nav controller did not show up when I present `CNContactViewController.init(forNewContact: CNContact)`. This below code works on earlier xcode 8 beta. But not working on xcode 8 beta 6 and GM.

```
    let a = CNContact()
    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactViewController.init(forNewContact: a) // iOS Editor
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self

    let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: contactPickerViewController)
    present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tried set navigation controller bar hidden to false but still did not show up.

`nav.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`